# Overloading subscript operator in a template class

Tags: c++, generics, operator-overloading

I am trying to implement a generic (template) bidirectional linked list, similar to C#.NET implementation.

I wanted to build a "short cut" method to get at element with a certain index and decided to go with the subscript operator. I did just like in the instructions, and came up with something like this.

```
template <typename  T>
class List
{
public:
    T& operator[] (int index) 
    { 
        return iterator->GetCurrentValue(); //iterator is of type Iterator<T> and returns T&
    }
};
```

however when I get to use this in my code:

```
List<int>* myList = new List<int>();
...
int value=myList[i]; //i is int
```

I get a compiler error: `main.cpp:18: error: cannot convert 'List<int>' to 'int' in initialization` on the last line.

I tried it to return value, not reference, but still the same error.

Why is it interpreting `int` return value as `List<int>`?

I am using NetBeans with Cygwin gcc-c++.

Comment: The list typically doesn't overload operator[] because it's not a random access container. Also, there is std::list or std::vector which are existing standard template classes you might want to use. Also, your index value seems to be ignored. What is the intent of his?

Comment: I'll look into std::list, thanks for the suggestion. `index` value is used, I just stripped the unnecessary code to be placed here. It didn't work even when I did `int i=5; return i;` so I figured the rest of the code is not important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it interpreting `int` return value as `List<int>`?

It's not.  `myList` is a pointer to a `List`, it's not a `List` itself.  You'd need to use `(*myList)[i]`.

It's quite unlikely that you really need dynamic allocation in this scenario, so my suggestion would be to not use a pointer, and to not use `new`.

Comment: Just to clarify Oli's last comment for those not familiar with C++. That means replacing `List<int>* myList = new List<int>();` with `List<int> myList;`.